# Moving an R plot side to side

Tags: r, plot

I'm using `plot()` to create a map with a legend and because of the shape of the map, it overlaps with the legend. I'm still learning R, but how can I move the map slightly to the left to reduce overlap? I'm sure there's a simple fix, but I was not able to find the right parameter.

Thanks for your help! I'm new to R (and stackoverflow) so I cannot post an image unfortunately.

EDIT: Here's the code that I'm running:

```
plot(spdfCounties, bg="gray90", col=findColours(ciFisher, colRamp))
title("Fisher-Jenks")
strLegend = paste(
  "$", format(round(ciFisher$brks[-(intClasses + 1)]), big.mark=","), " - ", 
  "$", format(round(ciFisher$brks[-1]), big.mark=","), sep=""
)
legMain = legend(
  "topright", legend=strLegend, 
  title="Median Income, 2010", bg="gray", inset=0.02, cex=0.6,
  fill=colRamp
)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used to generate the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mar` (for margin) options in `par`. From `?par`

> `mar` A numerical vector of the form `c(bottom, left, top, right)` which
>   gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on the four sides
>   of the plot. The default is `c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1`.

So, if your legend is on the right, make your right margin bigger by entering

`par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 8) + 0.1)`

Some trial and error should be able to get it right.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5789982/903061) about resetting par values may also be helpful. In general, you can always do `dev.off()` to close the device, and a new device will start with the default `par` settings.

---

**EDIT:** Adapting @Hugh's example

```
x <- runif(1000)
y <- runif(1000)
plot(x, y)  
legend('topright', legend = "points")  # overlaps points

par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 8) + 0.2)
plot(x, y) 
legend('right', legend = "points", inset = -.3, xpd = T)
# The correct right margin and inset value will depend
# on the size of your graphic device.
```

Adjusting the margins results in

[image: Extra margin area]

Adding white space to the graph, as in @Hugh's answer, looks like this:

[image: White space inside plot]

---

**Edit 2**

Trying to adapt new code from question. You're still using base graphics' `plot` function, so nothing should be special about having a map. However, we don't have your data, so we can't really test anything. (If this doesn't work---and regardless before posting another question---you should look at tips for making [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).)

```
dev.off() # to reset par
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 8))
plot(spdfCounties, bg="gray90", col=findColours(ciFisher, colRamp))
# the margins are set as soon as you call plot()
title("Fisher-Jenks")
strLegend = paste(
  "$", format(round(ciFisher$brks[-(intClasses + 1)]), big.mark=","), " - ", 
  "$", format(round(ciFisher$brks[-1]), big.mark=","), sep=""
)
legMain = legend(
  "right", # changed the legend to right
  legend=strLegend, 
  title="Median Income, 2010",
  bg="gray",
  inset= -0.3, # negative inset to put it outside of the plotting region
  xpd = T,     # xpd set to allow plotting outside of the plot region
  cex=0.6,
  fill=colRamp
)
```

Comment: Is this right? The legend is contained within the plot area which wouldn't be affected by changes to mar (beyond the plot area).

Comment: @Hugh We don't have any code, so there's no reason to believe the legend is inside the plot area. The question is "how to move a plot side to side", and adjusting the margins does that. I often like to put the legend outside the plotting region (negative inset and setting `xpd` if necessary works well).

Comment: @Hugh and @shujaa thanks for the reply! your ideas seem good, but the map and legend appear to move in tandem/not create a margin. I've tried putting `par()` before the `plot()` and `legend()`, but both seemed to shrink the map with the legend. Is there a different issue because my plot is a map?

Comment: @shujaa those suggestions worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

As a one off, you can change the `lim` arguments of `plot` to create more space.

```
x <- runif(1000)
y <- runif(1000)
plot(x,y)  
legend('topright', legend = "points")  # overlaps points

plot(x,y, xlim = c(0, 1.5), ylim = c(0, 1.5)  # adds white space
legend('topright', legend = "points")
```