# Undo layout in R

Tags: r, layout, reset

I initially create a plot which is a combination of boxplot & histogram. For this I set

```
nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2),2,1, byrow=TRUE),  height = c(1,3))
par(mar=c(2,2,1,1))
# Draw box plot
# Draw histogram
```

After this I need to create a regular plot. But I find that all subsequent plots try to follow the same layout. One on top and another one below.

How can I reset the layout to default?

Should I use 
nf <- layout(mat = matrix(c(1,1),1,1, byrow=FALSE))

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: Yeah, just reset everything: `par(mfrow=c(1,1))`

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789982/reset-par-to-the-default-values-at-startup) as well which may give you a couple good ideas.

Comment: Andrew - This worked thanks! Sorry it looks like I flagged it by mistake. I wanted to upvote. How to undo the flag?  I will accept your answer

Comment: Looks fine. Answer added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Other good answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789982/reset-par-to-the-default-values-at-startup)

Answer (score 1):

*You should save the par's before change it, and use it during the initialization.*

Exemple :

```
### #data set
df = iris
### #Save par's version
par_temp = par()
### #change par's
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(df[,1:2])
hist(df[,1])
### #initialization of par's
par(par_temp)
hist(df[,1])
```