# How to draw a plot on the next device after a layout in Rstudio?

Tags: r, layout, plot, rstudio, device

I have a code with several plots, some of them are in layouts and others stand alone. The problem is when I draw a layout, the next plots, that must be alone, appears in the previous layout arrangement. How can I stop the layout arrangement for the plots after a layout?

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2))
plot(1:10)
plot(10:100)
plot(100:1000)
plot(1000:10000)


#Plots that I dont't want into a layout

plot(1, main = "Example 1")

plot(2, main = "Example 2")
```

When I run the entire code, I expected in the Rstudio window, a layout and then 2 separated plots, but I get:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: you can reest it with `layout(1)`, or `par(mfrow=c(1,1))` or `dev.off()`

Comment: poss duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079546/undo-layout-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can run the following line to reset the plot device setting.

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 1))
```

After that, run the code you provided and the plots are all in single frame.

```
plot(1, main = "Example 1")
```

[image]

```
plot(2, main = "Example 2")
```

[image]