# not enough horizontal space to display frequencies

Tags: r

I am attempting to use the `aggr()` function of the `VIM` package to plot missing data patterns. My plots don't show the frequencies/proportions of missing data patterns to the outside of the right-side axis. Should look like [this](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/4625_fa990d611f024ea69e7e2b10dd228fe7.html). I'm getting an error that there is "not enough horizontal space to display frequencies".

```
library(VIM)
aggr(sleep, prop = T, numbers = T)
```

I don't do much base R plotting. I think this has something to do with margins. I reviewed [this informative tutorial on margins](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Graphics/Basics/mar-oma/index.htm), but I did not find my way to a solution.

Comment: I have no problem. Did you run it inside a clean session of R?

Comment: I just cleared the environment and reran. Same issue. RStudio Version 0.99.489 on Mac.

Comment: Simply running these two lines? No customized `par` defined previously?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with base plotting, but I ran `dev.off()` and checked `par()$mar`: `5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1`. That's the default, right?

Comment: Yes, but according to the code source, this error is related to `par("pin")`.

Comment: OK, got it. `par("pin")`: `2.902222 4.824444`. I found this custom function to reset par and it worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789982/reset-par-to-the-default-values-at-startup. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Create an answer. Might be useful for `aggr` users facing the same error.

Comment: will do. it's not working on my actual use case yet, but i did resolve for the toy example. i'll try to resolve for my case first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had two problems: one localized and one related to `aggr()`.

1) [This function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789982/reset-par-to-the-default-values-at-startup) helped me to reset `par("pin")`. Resetting made the toy example work.

```
resetPar <- function() {
    dev.new()
    op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
    dev.off()
    op
}
par(resetPar())
```

2) My actual use case was still failing with the same horizontal space error. I realized I needed to set the `cex.numbers` parameter of `aggr()` to something less than 1.