# r - Missing Value Analysis - VIM - not enough vertical space to display frequencies

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to visualize missing data patterns.  I am using the aggr() function from the VIM package and keep receiving this Warning message:

> In plot.aggr(res, ...) :   not enough vertical space to display
>   frequencies (too many combinations)

The problem is caused because I am trying to show too much data and cannot figure out how to resize the plot to allow for the extra data. I have 20 variables I'm trying to visualize and it will not fit.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34347540/not-enough-horizontal-space-to-display-frequencies) question but the solution does not work.

I've created an example that demonstrates the problem:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(25,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), 
          prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))

aggr(df2, plot = TRUE, combined=TRUE, sortVars=FALSE, sortCombs=TRUE,
    numbers=TRUE, prop=c(FALSE, FALSE), only.miss=FALSE, cex.numbers=.6,
    cex.axis=.6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realise that this doesn't answer how to do this in VIM, but here are some other methods for visualising missing data using

- [visdat](http://visdat.njtierney.com/)
- [extracat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extracat/index.html)
- [naniar](http://naniar.njtierney.com/)

```r
df <- data.frame(replicate(25,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), 
                                                        prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))


# visualise using visdat
visdat::vis_miss(df2)
```

[image]

```r
# apply clustering
visdat::vis_miss(df2, cluster = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
# sort the rows
visdat::vis_miss(df2, sort_miss = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
# visualise the number of missings in cases using visna from extracat
extracat::visna(df2)
```

[image]

```r
# sort by rows
extracat::visna(df2, sort = "r")
```

[image]

```r
# sort by columns
extracat::visna(df2, sort = "c")
```

[image]

```r
# visualise the number of missings in each variable using naniar `gg_miss_var`
naniar::gg_miss_var(df2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Nick Tierney, this provided me the visual I needed.  Really appreciate it!