# Titles cut off when using bargraph.CI

Tags: r, plot

How do I fix this? My code looks like this:

```
bargraph.CI( species, response = lcr, group = Rztype, data = p1data, cex.lab = 2, legend =T, ylim = c(0,100), col = c("grey", "light green", "dark green"), ylab = "Live crown ratio (%)", xlab = "Species")
```

Plot of titles cut off:

[image: plot of titles cut off]

I have also attached a screenshot of the plot above.

Answer (score 2):

it would be helpful if you included a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example).

With the information given, though, you might try dragging/widening the plot viewer in RStudio to allow for more space for the plot itself. The plot image will readjust in size and resolution, and the titles may show up thereafter.

You could also try clicking the Export button then Copy to Clipboard. This will allow you to adjust height and width, as well as see updated previews before copying.

Comment: When I drag it to make it wider, the Live Crown Ratio text is still cut off.

Comment: Just edited my answer - see if that yields anything!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately editing the width and height did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Brett that a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) is needed to understand and address your specific issue.

That being said, here's a guess. When you increase the font size of the axis labels using `cex.lab`, the y-axis label is cut off. Here's a reproducible example of this issue using the first example from the help file for `bargraph.CI`, which I accessed by entering `?bargraph.CI` into the console. I modified the example by increasing the axis labels from the default (`cex.lab=1` to `cex.lab=2`) and making up some axis labels.

```
library(sciplot)
data(ToothGrowth)
bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = ToothGrowth,
            cex.lab = 2, xlab= "Dose", ylab = "Odontoblast length")
```

[image]

**Solution 1** Suppress the y-axis label when you make the plot and then add the axis label separately, closer to the y-axis.

```
bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = ToothGrowth,
            cex.lab = 2, xlab= "Dose", ylab = "") 
mtext(side=2,text="Odontoblast length",cex=2,line = 2.2)
```

[image]

**Solution 2** Adjust the graphical parameters before you draw the plot, using `par`. Specifically, you could adjust the margin on the left hand side of the plot with `mar`. The margins are defined by `par(mar = c(bottom, left, top, right)`, and the default is `par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)`. You would want to increase the value of the left hand margin. If you do this, just be aware that you may want to [reset these values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789982/reset-par-to-the-default-values-at-startup) before you draw new plots.

```
par(mar = c(5, 5, 4, 2) + 0.1)
bargraph.CI(x.factor = dose, response = len, data = ToothGrowth,
            cex.lab = 2, xlab= "Dose", ylab = "Odontoblast length")
```

[image]